# How can I mount NFS directory on Unity?

Tags: unity, nfs, sharing

An NFS directory is shared by a SPARC server.

Utilizing a Samba application, it is not a problem to link a folder shared by an MS-Windows server.

But, it is hard to link a directory shared by an NFS server on Unity.

What should I do to link?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. First you need to install the package nfs-common:

```
apt-get install nfs-common
```

If the nfs server is already set, you need to add this  line on the `/etc/exports` to allow your client to access:

```
/File_to_share_on_the_server/ 192.168.1.x(rw,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,sync)
```

Replace `192.168.1.x` by your client's IP.

I guess this step can be  done by the GUI on your Sparc server.

On your client, just need to mount your share now:

**Temporary:**

```
mount -t nfs -o rw 192.168.x.x:/File_to_share_on_the_server /mnt/yourfolder
```

**Permanent:**  Add a line in your  `/etc/fstab` :

```
192.168.x.x:/File_to_share_on_the_server      /mnt/yourfolders    nfs     defaults  0 2
```

This time `192.168.x.x` must to be replace by the IP of your server. You can find lots of tutorial on the web to install & configure nfs...